# Why incrementing transform.position in unity causes jitter on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am having some problems with a simple script which causes jitter on the sprite. All the script does is:

```
public float speed; 

void Update () 
{ 
    var pos = transform.position;
    pos.y += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = pos; 
}
```

This code runs fine in Editor or standalone builds, but when I try to run it on my iOS device, I see some jittering. The scene has 3 gameobjects with the above script and there is no rigidbody physics. It's just three objects falling without any physics.

Any idea why it causes jittering?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are creating a new `var pos` in `Update()`.

`Update()` is called once every frame, and therefore `pos` is being created as a new variable every frame, slowing down calculation time, which is why it is jittery.

Create your `var pos` outside of the `Update()` method, and this should fix the issue :)

Comment: look difference between local variables and fields. local variables don't stuck the program (if you don't fill the stack). They are used and deleted at the end of the function. So I think problem is not var Pos in Update

Comment: @tom That is a good point but it shouldn't make a difference for something as small as that. It is definitely something else!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> Time.fixedDeltaTime

instead of

> Time.deltaTime

like i have done in the following code snippet.

```
public float speed; 

void Update () 
{ 
    var pos = transform.position;
    pos.y += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = pos; 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Edit:
If above isn't working, then try putting it in coroutine like below:

```
IEnumerator Move(){
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position += Vector3.up*step;
    }
}
```

Call the above coroutine in Start() by

> StartCoroutine(MoveTo);

Comment: I have already tried using FixedDeltaTime and it didn't fix it!